# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound - Product without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to create a review in my app however when I am doing the following in my controller:

```
def create
    @product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @review = @product.reviews.create(params[:review])

   redirect_to product_path(product)
  end
```

I get `Couldn't find Product without an ID`. I fill the form out and some where along the lines when it does the following line `@product = Product.find(params[:product_id])` it cannot seem to find the product

**routes**

```
 resources :products do
    resource :reviews
  end
```

**products/show.html.erb**

```
 <%= form_for(@product.reviews.build) do |f| %>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :title %>
     <br/>
     <%= f.text_field :title %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :author %>
     <br/>
     <%= f.text_field :author %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :content %>
     <br/>
     <%= f.text_area :content %>
   </div>
   <div class="field">
     <%= f.label :rating %>
     <br/>
     <%= f.number_field :rating %>
   </div
   <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit %>
   </div>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Could you post your params? I believe your `params` method doesn't have a :product_id key.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change your form_for to

```
form_for [@product, @product.reviews.build] do |f|
```

this changes the action to `/products/@product.id/reviews` to match your nested route

Comment: I tried this before and made my form_for look like the following: `<%= form_for([@product, @product.reviews.build]) do |f| %>` but got `undefined local variable or method 'product'` which was pointing to the create method of my review_controller

Comment: I believe the issue is that in my `review_controller` it is saying `Product` is not defined?

Comment: did you try it again?  your issue is `params[:product_id]` is nil so an exception was raised that a product can't be found without an id.  I'm assuming that since you're in the show action of product, `@product` is already a persisted object so this would solve your issue.  if you're getting a different error when you try this solution, add that error to your question.

Comment: I forgot to mention that controller code is in the `review_controller`. And yes I did try again.

Comment: i know. that form should go to the create action of the reviews controller.

Comment: So you suggesting to remove the `@product = Product.find(params[:product_id])` as it is already a persisted object? I'd be intrigued myself who downvoted. Like I say I initially did try the way you suggested

Comment: no. just change the form to use my answer. then if you get any other error, share that error here. I'm 100% sure that your issue is with `params[:product_id]` being `nil` and the right way to send the product_id is to change the form_for to reflect that review is nested under product.